# What does this bash ssh command do on remote machine

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have to maintain a bash script. 
There several commands are executed via ssh on a remote machine. The following command is used to do so:

```
ssh $1@$2 ${SSH_OPTS:-} "${CONFIG}; REC=y . \$HOME/.profile; $3 2>&1"
```

I have some troubles to understand what `REC=y . \$HOME/.profile;` does. Something with sourcing the .profile on the remote machine but what is `REC=y`for?

Comment: if you look in the remote $HOME/.profile, you should find a variable `$REC` That assignment sets it's value to `y`. So it is performing an override of a default condition where $REC is either unset, or has a different default value, possibly set like `: ${REC:=n}` (or other methods) . Good luck.

Comment: I tried to verify your comment. So I have created a local script containing "REC=y . $HOME/.profile; echo $REC" and added "export REC=n" to my local profile. When I run that script locally there is no output at all. REC seems not to be set at all. What am I missing?

Comment: `VAR=val command` sets the value of the environment variable `VAR` to the value `val` in the environment of `command` but leaves it unmodified in the current shell environment.

Comment: Try that on multiple lines and not a single line. A single line expands is being expanded all at once.

Comment: @EtanReisner Does that mean, that REC is set to y while sourcing the profile (in a subshell) and afterwards $3 is executed but REC has no effect?

Comment: @EtanReisner Even if my local script is split into two lines, I don't get any output. I am using bash 4.3 on ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Correct, `$3` is expanded by the current shell (on the local machine) and `REC` is only given the value `y` while sourcing the `.profile` script (unless the `.profile` script then exports `REC` itself or something.

Comment: `echo 'export REC' > profile; (REC=y; . profile; echo "REC=$REC"); rm -f profile` works here.

Comment: as does `... (REC=y . profile; ...)` :-) Good luck to all.

Comment: @Martin, sorry, but your "I tried to verify your comment" comment is ambiguous (to me). If it is important to you, please update your Q with exact dirs/filenames, content, and output from running that test setup. OR add `set -vx` to test file setup to see debug/trace. `+` lines indicate "running exactly this, with any/all variable substitutions". Good luck.

Comment: @Martin ${CONFIG} is expanded by the local shell and executed remotely. The CONFIG variable name suggests that some environment variables are set, but you could let us see the value of CONFIG variables. These possible environment modifications apply for the rest of the commands. Next, the REC variable is assigned with y value which will apply just for the sourcing of the $HOME/.profile. This later sourcing will possibly also modify the environment which will apply to the last command executed: $3. Finally what are the values of $SSH_OPTS $CONFIG and $3?

Comment: I'd like to accept Jay's answer. Since this was only a comment, I can't do that. If you write this as an answer i will accept it. fyi: CONFIG set some environment variables but non was related.